# Translate a C++ graphical program to Web?

Tags: web-apps, c++, pixel-graphics

I have a collection of little educational games that I wrote some 15 to 20 years ago, dual-targeted for Mac and Windows. They are written in C++, and use native 2D graphics on each operating system. I shared them off of my website, available for downloading. Well, the world has moved on. Such things are now normally shared as web-based games, no downloading required. People are more comfortable with that because of the reduced risk of viruses.

So here I am with some delightful but semi-obsolete code. My question: are there any tools out there that might be useful to me, any path to getting these programs on the web short of recoding from scratch?

Comment: Maybe libonion. See https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/ , but in 15 years C++ changed a lot!

Comment: Are your C++ source code open source and available at some URL? Which one?

Comment: "People are more comfortable with that because of the reduced risk of viruses." - please don't go that route just because something seems "hip and fashionable". First, I'd wager that the vast majority of users are not concerned about malware as much as they are scared of the seemingly "technical" process of running an installer. I have found many users to be woefully unaware of what's the difference between running a locally installed application vs. running something in a browser (and by extension, why one would be safer concerning malware than the other). ...

Comment: ... Thus, the goal is ease of launching. The downsite for users is that availability of the application depends on whether the user can reach the website - which introduces both connectivity of the user and survival of the producer as points of failure. There are techniques for applications to make the setup process more or less invisible during the first launch. And also, there are ways to package what is basically a web app into a redistributable, locally runnable application. You may want to explore these for long-lasting user happiness ;)